# Does SwiftMailer support asynchronous mail sending the way Mail_Queue does?

Tags: swiftmailer, mail-queue

I want to send my emails using sendgrid's SMTP servers, but connecting to them, not at "Web-time", but via a (simple) queue.

I know PEAR's Mail_Queue can enable me to do that, but can I do it using SwiftMailer?

(What are exactly the fonctional differences between SwiftMailer and Mail_Queue?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SwiftMailer has options for a 'spool'. There are details in the [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html). There are also Symfony bundles that extend this system to spool via a database, such as the [WhiteOctoberSwiftMailerDBBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberSwiftMailerDBBundle).

From the cookbook:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool:
        type: file
        path: /path/to/spool
```

Now, when your app sends an email, it will not actually be sent but instead added to the spool. Sending the messages from the spool is done separately. There is a console command to send the messages in the spool:

```
php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```